# Upgrading to VS2022 17.6 has messed up all of my .net maui layouts

Tags: maui

I use Grids to layout my screens in .net maui and prior to VS2022 17.6 this was working fine. After upgrading, the width of all of the grids goes off screen causing every other control to be misplaced.

There is mention at [The Developer Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-6-now-available/) that they did the following

*Bug Fixes
Treat */Auto spans as resolvable finite measures rather than infinite - 14667
[net7.0] Ensure that Grid is treating star rows/columns as Auto when unconstrained - 14165*

I'm not clear what this means exactly and if it is now working as intended or is broken. For now I have rolled back to VS2022 17.5.2. Since I am new at this I suspect the technique I use might be an issue:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="25*,50*,25*">
    <Label 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</Grid>
```

This used to very conveniently split the screen into 3 columns taking up 25%, 50% and 25% of the screen * as long as the numbers added up to 100 ). In 17.6 it goes off screen and the middle column is no longer in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Rollback the version?

Comment: Is 1,2,1 working? Or is it the same?

Comment: I did rollback to 17.5.2 as I said in the original message and everything works well.

Comment: Your Stars technique is fine. (FYI: Stars don’t have to add up to 100.) It sounds like 14165 has broken your code. Is Grid inside of ScrollView? If not, please make a public github repo with just enough code to run and see the problem.  Add a comment with link to repo, at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/14165

Comment: Ah good, thanks for confirming there was no issue with handling stars like that. It's not in a scrollview - the grid is the top level component on the page. I'll whip up a demo and post it to it to that repo.

Comment: Hi @sheldon.parkes, could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: I may have been on the wrong tangent here. I just upgraded to 17.6.1 and everything seemed fine. So I went ahead and upgraded xcode to 14.3 and debugged using an iOS 16.4 simulator ( was using 16.2 before ) and now the app crashes at the splash screen. Still investigating this problem.

Comment: I see there are issues with 16.4 and maui.  https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14421